# Autodesk TranslationWorker-InternalFailure

Tags: autodesk, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When attempting to translate [this file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByY6IA02pFulZTFEekZLNURQblk/view?usp=sharing) using `POST https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/register` I receive the following error:

```
{
            "guid" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLXhwZm92YWltMjY5NmN1M2lyZXcya2UyOS5pcHQ",
            "success" : "0%",
            "hasThumbnail" : "false",
            "progress" : "complete",
            "urn" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLXhwZm92YWltMjY5NmN1M2lyZXcya2UyOS5pcHQ",
            "status" : "failed",
            "startedAt" : "Thu May 18 05:39:58 UTC 2017",
            "region" : "US",
            "owner" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLXhwZm92YWltMjY5NmN1M2lyZXcya2UyOS5pcHQ=",
            "type" : "design",
            "children" : [
                {
                    "guid" : "aa85aad6-c480-4a35-9cbf-4cf5994a25ba",
                    "messages" : [
                        {
                            "type" : "error",
                            "message" : "Translation failure",
                            "code" : "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                        }
                    ],
                    "name" : "LMV Bubble",
                    "hasThumbnail" : "false",
                    "role" : "viewable",
                    "version" : "2.0",
                    "progress" : "complete",
                    "urn" : "dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6c3RlbW4vNTkxY2U3NzAzNzFhMjEwMmM3MWQwMTgzLXhwZm92YWltMjY5NmN1M2lyZXcya2UyOS5pcHQ",
                    "status" : "failed",
                    "type" : "folder"
                }
            ]
        }
```

What is causing the `TranslationWorker-InternalFailure` error? If this `v1` api is to be deprecated, what should be used instead? The `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job` api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologizing for your inconvenience caused, View and Data API (well known as v1 API) is scheduled to be closed down on July 17, 2017. Therefore, you should start migrating your application form the View and Data API(v1) to the Forge API(v2), see more detail via [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/end-life-notice-view-and-data-api).

However, I had tried translate the model you provided via both APIs of the [Data Management](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/overview/) and the [Model Derivative](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/), and I got a well translated one without any error message. The result I got is like this: 
[image: blade_main_result]

Result on the viewer:
[image: blade_main_Viewer]

Here are some tips for Forge API migration:

1. Upload files to the bucket: `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/oss/v1/buckets/{BucketName}/objects/{Filename}` => `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/oss/v2/buckets/{BucketName}/objects/{Filename}`
2. Request a model translation job: `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/viewingservicev1/register` => `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job`
3. Check the translation status: `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/viewingservicev1/{base64URN}/status` =>
   `{ApiEntryPoint_URL}/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{base64URN}/manifest`

Comment: Thank you, your v1 => v2 mappings are very helpful!